# Getting generic page error in response, using JMeter in .NET site

Tags: testing, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

When using .Net application,
and checking error logs,
getting below error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're sending the wrong request due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

So if you have recorded a request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) most probably there is at least one parameter there which is supposed to be dynamic, to wit

- extracted from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
- stored into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- and the dynamic variable to be sent along with the request instead of recorded hard-coded value

In .NET web applications the most commonly used parameter is [ViewState](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/), however other may also be required like [EventValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Page_EnableEventValidation)

so given you properly handle these dynamic parameters you should start getting "good" responses, see [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) for example handling of the dynamic parameters.

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan.

Comment: I m trying with 50 users, out of which 35 cases are passing, and in remaining getting the above-mentioned error.